# Cant install magento/pwa

Tags: error, setup, windows, yarn

I am trying to install Magento with pwa,but when i run in terminal command yarn create @magento/pwa, 
and after answer of the question-  
Im getting an error-- Invalid directory path; contains illegal characters

Answer (score 1):

The `yarn create @magento/pwa` command does not work in Windows, and the Magento's team does not want to fix it: [github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues/2342#issuecomment-620161213](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues/2342#issuecomment-620161213)
A workaround is to use the `npx @magento/pwa-buildpack create-project` command, e.g.:

```
npx @magento/pwa-buildpack create-project . \
    --author "Dmitry Fedyuk" \
    --backend-url "https://localhost.com:2205" \
    --braintree-token "sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk" \
    --name "pwa_studuo_2021_01_14" \
    --npm-client "npm" \
    --template "venia-concept"
```

[How do I install Magento PWA Studio to Windows?](https://mage2.pro/t/6230)
[magento.github.io/pwa-studio/pwa-buildpack/reference/buildpack-cli/create-project](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/pwa-buildpack/reference/buildpack-cli/create-project)